# php check before pdf2swf failed copying

Tags: php, pdf, pdf2swf

i have a problem. I use the pdf2swf tool to convert a pdf so that i can display it on a website.
Most of the PDF`s will be converted.

But today i found a PDF on the site that can`t be displayed because the converting failed.

it throws this message

```
FATAL   PDF disallows copying
```

i know that it is because of the security settings in the pdf.
But i want to know if it is possible to check in php if the pdf has such an restriction.

So that i can show a message if the pdf can`t be converted.

thanks

EDIT: i found the solution for the problem.. the pdf`s was protected from copying so that pdf2swf didn't have the permissions to copy or manipulate the pdf.. just as information if someone else have the same problem

Comment: found the problem.. if the pdf is password protected then pdf2swf will throw this error.. just fyi